# Paste multiple rows and generate ID for them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm using a code that create unique ID's. The problem i'm facing is when I retreive a list of 10 rows and paste it on the column B, the code generate ID only for the first row. So I have to copy/paste row by row in order to generate the ID
is there a way to modifiy the code in a way that allow to generate ID for more than a row at once ?

```
/* ***Custom Unique ID***
 *
 * onEdit of the selected new cell, Custom Unique ID:
 *  1. Sorts through the ID column
 *  2. Finds the largest value
 *  3. Adds 1 to this value and inserts this at the next unique ID.
 *
 * The ID column must have at least 1 Unique ID for the program to reference.
 *
 * Custom Unique ID can take ID's with:
 *  -Leading letters
 *  -Leading Zeroes
 *  -Trailing Letters
 *
 * -Trailing and leading letters must be of the same length.
 * -Letters cannnot be between numbers. For example, ARG00123B025AG.
 * -ID must be of same length. e.g. FE100er has a length of 7 characters. Subsequent 
 *  IDs must be of the same length. Ensure you have sufficient leading zeroes e.g. KRG0002345
 *
 * Custom Unique ID Can take multiple sheet and cell locations. See "var locations".
 * Unique ID's won't be deleted when other cell data is changed or edited. 
 */

// Location format = [sheet, ID Column, ID Column Row Start, Edit Column]
var locations = [
  ["Liste",3,2,2],
];

function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  //Entry data
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();

  // Location Data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  function getNewID(){
    function IDrange(){
      var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
      var lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();

      return sheet.getRange(IDrowStart,IDcol,lastRow-IDrowStart).getValues();
    };

    //Get largest Value in range
    function getLastID(range){
      var sorted = range.sort();
      var lastIDval = sorted[sorted.length-1][0];

      return lastIDval;

    };
    //Stores leading letters and zeroes and trailing letters
    function getLettersNzeroes(id){

      //Get any letters or zeroes.
      var re = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0])$");
      var letterZero = [];
      for(char = 0; char < id.length; char++){
        if(re.test(id[char])){
          letterZero.push([char,id[char]]);// [[position, letter or zero]]
        };
      };

      // Categorize letters and zeroes into start and end blocks
      var startLetterZero = "", 
          endLetter = "",
          len = letterZero.length - 1;
      for(j = 0; j < letterZero.length; j++){
        if(letterZero[j][0] === j){
          startLetterZero += letterZero[j][1];
        }else if(letterZero[j][1] !== "0" && letterZero[len][0] - (len - j) == letterZero[j][0]){
          endLetter += letterZero[j][1];
        };
      };
      var startNend = {"start":startLetterZero,"end":endLetter};

      return startNend;
    };

    //Gets last id number. Adds 1 an checks to set if its  new length is greater than the lastNumber.
    function getNewNumber(id){
      var removeZero = false;

      var lastNum = parseInt(id.replace(/\D/g,''),10);//Remove letters
      var newNum = (lastNum+1).toString();

      if(lastNum.toString().length !== newNum.length){
        var removeZero = true;
      };
      var newNumSet = {"num":newNum, "removeZero": removeZero};

      return newNumSet
    };

    var lastID = getLastID(IDrange());
    var lettersNzeroes = getLettersNzeroes(lastID);
    var newNumber = getNewNumber(lastID);

    //If the number is 9,99,999,9999 etc we need to remove a zero if it exists.
    if(newNumber.removeZero === true && lettersNzeroes.start.indexOf("0")  !== -1.0){
      lettersNzeroes.start = lettersNzeroes.start.slice(0,-1);
    };

    //Rejoin everything together
    var newID = lettersNzeroes.start +
                newNumber.num +
                lettersNzeroes.end;

    return newID;  
  };

  for(i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
    var sheetID = locations[i][0],
        IDcol   = locations[i][1],
        IDrowStart = locations[i][2],
        EditCol = locations[i][3];

    var offset = IDcol - EditCol;
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

    if(sheetID === sheet.getName()){
      if(EditCol === col){
        //ID Already Exists the editing cell isn't blank.
        if(cell.offset(0,offset).isBlank() && cell.isBlank() === false){
          var newID = getNewID();
          cell.offset(0,offset).setValue(newID);
        };
      };
    }; 
  };        
};
```

Comment: Short answer: Yes, there is. Do you already understand the code that you included in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

For achieving what you are aiming for you will need a for loop where you set each row of the column you just paste separately. `e.range` will return the whole range of the cells changed, it can be one or several cells.

Therefore, just setting an indivual cell in the last stage *(without the for loop)* it will not be enough as it either will only set the first cell of the range pasted or set all of them with the same values.

To solve this **change this part of your script**:

```js
    var offset = IDcol - EditCol;
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

    if(sheetID === sheet.getName()){
      if(EditCol === col){
        //ID Already Exists the editing cell isn't blank.
        if(cell.offset(0,offset).isBlank() && cell.isBlank() === false){
          var newID = getNewID();
          cell.offset(0,offset).setValue(newID);
        };
```

for the following (the code has self explanatory comments):

```js
  var offset = IDcol - EditCol;
  var cell = e.range;
  // This is done so that we know exactly how many rows we are trying to copy/paste for
  // iterating over each of these rows in our for loop
  var values = cell.getValues().flat();

  if(sheetID === sheet.getName()){
    if(EditCol === col){
      //ID Already Exists the editing cell isn't blank.
      if(cell.offset(0,offset).isBlank() && cell.isBlank() === false){
      // for every row we are pasting
        for(i=0;i<values.length;i++){
            var newID = getNewID();
            // set the value of the cell in that range of rows (when i=0 this will be the first
            // cell in the range you are pasting, when i=1 it will be the next cell, etc
            sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow() + i, e.range.getColumn()).offset(0,offset).setValue(newID);            
            }

      };
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: This is just awesome what you have done here! Thank you so much for your help.